# Finding Mean Value of a data list excluding some entries in Python

Tags: python, database, list

I have a list of data e.g. `A = [1,2,3,10,4,3.5,16,11,19,6,13]`
Now I want to find the mean value of this data set when entry value is less than 10. 
How can I do it in Python?

Comment: `sum(A1)/len(A1)`. Or, if you want the first `n` numbers from `A`: `sum(A[:n])/n`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `statistics.mean`

```
from statistics import mean

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(mean(a)) # 5.5
```

Comment: This is a cool answer

Answer (score 2):

You can get sub list using list [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/12459817) - `A[start:stop:step]`

**python3.***:

```py
>>> sum(A[:10]) / 10    # 10:is length of your sublist
5.5
```

**python2.***:

```py
>>> from __future__ import division   # to get float division like python3
>>> sum(A[:10]) / 10    # 10:is length of your sublist
5.5
```

Comment: I'm going to strongly suggest removing the Python 2 answer, since Python 2 is no longer supported, and should (thus) not be (promoted to be) used anymore.